# Variable output in script tag

Tags: javascript, html, variables

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if( liste[options]== "send") {
        var output ='src="js/Datei.js"';    <!--  src="js/Datei.js"   -->
    }
    else
    {
        alert('#3 Fehler: Datei Lesefehler - Nicht vorhanden oder nicht verfügbar!');
    }
</script>

<script  document.write('output'); ></script>
```

I want to output the following: `src="js/Datei.js"` to open the source in the script tag

Comment: Your structure has many mistakes. What program do you use?

Comment: [Deep dive into the murky waters of script loading](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var output = "js/Datei.js";    
var scriptTag   = document.createElement("script");
scriptTag.src   = output;
document.body.appendChild(scriptTag);
```